# Populate any textbox in an HTML table with one javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function, textbox

I have not posted on Stack in a long time so my apologies if my question is missing any obvious details for a solution.

Here is my problem: I have an html table with 20 rows, 5 columns of textboxes in each row. I have the rows populating values in 3 specific textboxes (Total pipes, total fitting, total other items) using the 'onchange' event in javascript functions. The way it works is you type in either 'pipe', 'fitting', or 'other' in a textbox, then you select the value 1,2,3,4, or 5 from a select drop-down. The select drop-down has an 'onchange' event. The 'onchange event then populates another textbox with 'total pipes being ordered' , 'total fitting items' being ordered or 'total other items ordered' based on if you typed 'pipe', 'fitting' or 'other' and which row you indicated this in.

For example, if you select 'pipes' and a quantity of '3' in row 1, then select 'pipes' and a quantity of '5' in row 7, the value in the 'total pipes' textbox has to show '8'.

My code is going to get out of hand quickly the direction I am going and I am sure there is a much simpler way to make this week.  Any help is appreciated.

Below is my code:

HTML

```
<table id="mainTbl1">
<tr>
<th><input type="text" id="txtItemBox" value="Item#" readonly=true></th>
<th><input type="text" id="txtItemBox" value="Item Type?" readonly=true> </th>
<th><input type="text" id="txtItemBox" value="Quantity" readonly=true></th>
<th><input type="text" id="txtItemBox" value="Size" readonly=true></th>
<th><input type="text" id="txtItemBox" value="Description" readonly=true></th>
<th><input type="text" id="txtItemBox" value="Unit Price" readonly=true></th>
<th><input type="text" id="txtItemBox" value="Extend Price" readonly=true></th></tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="" value="1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="seltype" /></td>
<td><select id="txtItemBoxVal2" onchange="populateUPrice()">
    <option value="0">-----</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>        
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select></td>
<td><input type="text" id="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txt2" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txt2e" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="" value="2" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="seltype2" /></td>
<td><select id="txtItemBoxVal3" onchange="populateUPrice2()">
    <option value="0">-----</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>        
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select></td>
<td><input type="text" id="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txt3" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="txt3e" /></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var stotal;
var s1, s2, s3, t1, t2, t3;

function populateUPrice() {
    // declare variable to hold quantity amount
    s1 = document.getElementById("txtItemBoxVal2").value;
    t1 = document.getElementById("seltype").value;

    stotal = s1;

    if (t1 == "pipe") {
        document.getElementById("seltype").innerHTML = "pipe"
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = s1;
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = "";
    } else if (t1 == "fitting") {
        document.getElementById("seltype").innerHTML = "fitting"
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = s1;
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = "";
    } else if (t1 == "other") {
        document.getElementById("seltype").innerHTML = "other"
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = s1;
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = "";
    }

    if (document.getElementById("txtItemBoxVal2")) {
        document.getElementById("txt2").value = "0.00"
    }
}

function populateUPrice2() {
    // declare variable to hold quantity amount
    s2 = document.getElementById("txtItemBoxVal3").value;
    t2 = document.getElementById("seltype2").value;

    stotal = parseInt(s1) + parseInt(s2);

    if (t1 == "pipe" && t2 == "pipe") {
        document.getElementById("seltype2").innerHTML = "pipe"
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = parseInt(stotal);
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = "";
    } else if (t1 == "fitting" && t2 == "fitting") {
        document.getElementById("seltype2").innerHTML = "fitting"
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = parseInt(stotal);
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = "";
    } else if (t1 == "other" && t2 == "other") {
        document.getElementById("seltype2").innerHTML = "other"
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = parseInt(stotal);
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = "";
    } else if (t1 == "pipe" && t2 == "fitting") {
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = s1;
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = s2;
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = "";
    } else if (t1 == "pipe" && t2 == "other") {
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = s1;
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = s2;
    } else if (t1 == "fitting" && t2 == "pipe") {
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = s2;
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = s1;
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = "";
    } else if (t1 == "fitting" && t2 == "other") {
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = s1;
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = s2;
    } else if (t1 == "other" && t2 == "pipe") {
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = s2;
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = s1;
    } else if (t1 == "other" && t2 == "fitting") {
        document.getElementById("pipeFt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("fittingsCt").value = s2
        document.getElementById("otherVal").value = s1;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("txtItemBoxVal3")) {
        document.getElementById("txt3").value = "0.00";
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: If you want something to apply to a group of elements then I recommend you use a class. `id` should be given to one element and only that element, for groups of elements you should assign them with a class attribute.

Comment: Thank for that suggestion, j08691. I will work with a class in place of the .id. I will post my code changes asap.

Comment: NewToJS, any chance you could provide a simple example for populating 1 or 2 textboxes with a class? I have been experimenting but I am missing something.